# Access web api running locally on aws ec2 instance from public internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, ssl, amazon-ec2, portforwarding

I have web service (C# rest api) running on locahost on aws ec2 instance (windows server).
How one can access mentioned api from public internet by virtual machine dns (i.e: `https://ec{...}.compute.amazonaws.com/{epi-endpoint}`)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best practice would be to have a setup with an API gateway in front of your localhost API (will provide security, SSL, and domain name).
In case that you want to expose instance dns (or IP address) directly (without any proxy), you will need to ensure that your instance is in the public subnet and reachable from the internet (ports open etc). Be careful, in this scenario, when you start/stop instance you will get new dns/IP and therefore I will suggest that you use API Gateway